# f# pattern match the opposite value

Tags: f#

I want a simple function which give the opposite value - return v2 if v==v1; return v1 if v==v2. I tried the following:

```
let oppose v v1 v2 =
    match v with
    | v1 -> v2
    | v2 -> v1
    | _ -> ""
```

But, I get the warnings:

```
warning FS0026: This rule will never be matched
warning FS0026: This rule will never be matched
```

And it doesn't work as expected:

```
> oppose "a" "a" "b"
val it : string = "b"
> oppose "b" "a" "b"
val it : string = "b"
```

I would expect to get "a" in second call. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names used in the match clause are names assigned to the result, not a check against the value.  You need to explicitly check:

```
let oppose v v1 v2 =
    match v with
    | a when a = v1 -> v2
    | b when b = v2 -> v1
    | _ -> ""
```

You can also use `if` instead of a match.  This can be simpler to read if you're checking against values, as in this case:

```
let oppose v v1 v2 =
    if v = v1 then v2
    elif v = v2 then v1
    else ""
```

Comment: Maybe you should add the if/elif/else way to do it which is a better fit than match in this case, as @nafu seems to begin it's F# journey ?

Comment: @Sehnsucht Sure ;) easy enough to add

Comment: Thanks!

Never been referred to as an "it" before :)